# Convert interface with nullable string property to string property

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

I have the following two interfaces, one which allows a nullable `vin`, the other that doesn't:

```
interface IVehicle {
    vin: string | null;
    model: string;
}

interface IVehicleNonNullVin {
    vin: string;
    model: string;
}
```

I want to able to convert a model from `IVehicle` to `IVehicleNonNullVin` in an execution path where I'm able to infer that `vin` is not `null`.

Consider this example:

```
const myVehicle: IVehicle = {
    vin: 'abc123',
    model: 'm3'
};

const needsVin = (_: IVehicleNonNullVin) => false;

if (myVehicle.vin === null) {
    throw new Error('null');
} else {
    needsVin(myVehicle);
 // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 'IVehicle' is not assignable to 'IVehicleNonNullVin'
}
```

Which returns the following error:

> Argument of type 'IVehicle' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IVehicleNonNullVin'.
> Types of property 'vin' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Even though I'm **positive** the property isn't nullable here.

**Q**: How can I convince TS that the existing model conforms to the type based on type checks in the code flow?

#### [Demo in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDUIAtgIDYoDeAsAFDIXIBuoAXMgM5hSgDmyAPsiAK554BuMpWQBbAPYATCHnpMWIVkNIBfMmVCRYiFBmy4CAOXEhDfPOlDIS5SjRBzmbZSInTZjJ4uVrSZBCZMYgCemDj4EPR64QTIALzWwnZ0yADkcABGCACMAEwAzKkANEkUbjL0qaKFZCrK-oFg3BAQkgyWIPHIABQA+lFhBhDGpuYdAJTxAHzI8HgMEPWkwDA9oqH6EQB09vFxCbz8kzYiYFhQ4gDuzdcAolAXUN2ph3ip4z7IMguJthQgLTaHW660GEQ+tSAA)

---

#### Workarounds

As a workaround, I can **cast the type** (but that ignores the existing type safety):

```
needsVin(myVehicle as IVehicleNonNullVin);
```

Or **build a new model** (but this doesn't scale well with lots of properties):

```
const nonNullVehicle: IVehicleNonNullVin = {
    model: myVehicle.model,
    vin: myVehicle.vin
}
needsVin(nonNullVehicle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**type predicate**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to define a user-defined type guard like this:

```
const isNonNullVin = (vehicle: IVehicle): vehicle is IVehicleNonNullVin =>{
    return vehicle.vin !== null
}

if (!isNonNullVin(myVehicle)) {
    throw new Error('null');
} else {
    needsVin(myVehicle);
}
```

> TypeScript will *narrow* that variable to that specific type if the original type is compatible.

[**Demo in TS Fiddle**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDUIAtgIDYoDeAsAFDIXIBuoAXMgM5hSgDmyAPsiAK554BuMpWQBbAPYATCHnpMWIVkNIBfMmVCRYiFBmy4CAOXEhDfPOlDIS5SjRBzmbZSInTZjJ4uVrSZBCZMYgCemDj4EPR64QTIALzWwnZ0yADkcABGCACMAEwAzKkANEkUbjL0qaKFZCrK-oFg3BAQkgyWIPHIABQA+lFhBhDGpuYdAJTxAHzI8HgMEPWkASBBwAwjZvwdXd1U+hEDBwTj9PsxKOtogxGbY1ZxUzYiUBBgPFCd50MAdPbIAEI4glePxaupSMAYD0Aes7ttQN1RKFjhBxpNnpQwFgoOIAO7NAkAUSguKg3VSoLwqXGPmQMgWiVsFBALTaHSRKIutNqQA)